# Foreman start can't find Procfile, deploying Django app to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

Seems like a fairly simple problem, but can't seem to figure it out. I've been following Heroku's Django instructions (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#using-a-different-wsgi-server)

I'm trying to create a Procfile, run it locally with Foreman start. I've downloaded and installed Gunicorn and Gevent already, manually added a .txt file called Procfile in my root (let me know if there's a better way to do this then adding new text file and naming it Procfile), but Foreman start keeps returning

```
 (venv)c:\users\chris\hellodjango>foreman start    
 ERROR: Procfile does not exist.
```

Here is my directory:

```
hellodjango/
.gitignore
manage.py
requirements.txt
Procfile.txt
hellodjango/
    __init__.py
    __init__.pyc
    settings.py
    settings.pyc
    urls.py
    urls.pyc
    wsgi.py
    wsgi.pyc
venv/
    Include/
    Lib/
    Scripts/
```

My requirements.txt contents are

```
Django==1.4.2
distribute==0.6.28
dj-database-url==0.2.1
psycopg2==2.4.5
wsgiref==0.1.2
gunicorn==0.15.0
```

And my Procfile.txt contents are

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

What am I missing and why can't my app find ProcFile?

Comment: For more info on deployting on Heroku, see http://v3.mike.tig.as/blog/2012/02/13/deploying-django-on-heroku/

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790691/procfile-not-found-heroku-python-app

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Procfile should not have a '.txt' extension. You have called it 'Procfile.txt'. Should be just 'Procfile'.