# Heroku cannot find runtime.txt when deploying Python app

Tags: python, heroku

I've been struggling with Heroku for a little while and I can't quite seem to figure my problem out. I have a runtime.txt in the root directory of my Python project that I am trying to deploy to Heroku, yet Heroku cannot find it for some reason. Every time I try deploying the app (I just keep creating/deleting new apps on Heroku) it just sends me this message:

```
 -----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.4.
```

It makes no sense because my runtime.txt is clearly in the same directory as my Procfile and requirements.txt yet it has no problem finding those.

For good measure, here is my runtime.txt:

```
python-3.3.2
```

My project is based in Python 3.3, so I can't just go with the default python-2.7.4.

This may be a weird special case, I couldn't find anybody else with my problem while Googling. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** For anyone who may have this problem in the future, a simple reboot fixed the problem for me. Don't know why I didn't try it earlier.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790691/procfile-not-found-heroku-python-app?rq=1

Comment: @ChadMiller I actually tried something like that before I posted this, didn't seem to help.

Comment: Python 3.3.2 appears to be no longer supported. Does anyone know a way to use Django with Python 3.x?