# Heroku app successfully deploying but receiving application Error when loading site

Tags: flask, heroku

2023-04-10T07:47:23.802472+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=liver-app.herokuapp.com request_id=61baa2c2-62c4-48cd-96d7-5eee5255b2ec fwd="41.44.192.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-04-10T07:47:24.185090+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=liver-app.herokuapp.com request_id=7f4c6700-7e88-4e28-837d-48d37b0c824e fwd="41.44.192.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

i tried to change procfile to Procfile but this isn't solve the problem and there is no extension in a file
Procfile -> web: gunicorn app:app
requirements.txt ->
flask
numpy
sklearn
gunicorn

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24905934/16218856
Edit: it works for me after changing Procfile
from `web: gunicorn app:app` to this `echo "web: python app.py" > Procfile`
thanks alot,